# Create an object after removing duplicates and adding calculations of individual elements in an array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to remove duplicate elements based on an attribute(family) and sum another attribute  based on identified duplicate elements.

```
[{family: "Mobile",total:30},
{family: "Mobile",total:20},
{family: "Mobile",total:50},
{family: "Laptop",total:20}]
```

i am expecting an array after removing duplicates and adding total as below

```
[{family: "Mobile",total:100}, 
{family: "Laptop",total:20}]
```

i tried using below code but it was not calculation total

```
var resultArray = this.list1.reduce((unique, o) => {
    if(!unique.some(obj => obj.family === o.family )) {
      unique.push(o);
    }
    return unique;
},[]);
console.log(resultArray ); `

Can you help me here
```

Comment: Can we rely on the desired and input object structures just being those two fields? family and total?

Comment: we have more fields on the element , i gave it as an example